# Regarding python Module in anaconda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am very new to python and i am trying to follow the cs231n course by doing coding examples using python.

I created the virtual environment ,based on this tutorial http://cs231n.github.io/setup-instructions/

After that i changed the environment in anaconda navigator also as follows,

[image]

Still , when i try to import the relevent packages i am getting a error.

```
import random
import numpy as np
from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-19cb248684d4> in <module>
      1 import random
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from cs231n.data_utils import load_CIFAR10
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cs231n'
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure this out ? I tried myself to fix this but i couldn't find a solution.

Thank you